# Configure Scalaxb SBT Plugin's Generated Source Code Location

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaxb

I've included `scalaxb` in my project using the `sbt-scalaxb` plugin. Everything is working great, but I'm not entirely happy with the default location where the source files are being placed. Currently the files are placed in `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-scalaxb/scalaxbGenerated` (with that last folder what I specified in my `build.sbt`.

I would prefer to store the source files (though NOT the compiled classes) into `src/main/scala/scalaxbGenerated`(or something similar). Does anyone know the setting that I can do this with? (I am assuming there is one, I just haven't been able to find it without digging through the scalaxb source code).

Below is mockup of what I mean.

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(ScalaxbPlugin) // See project/scalaxb.sbt
.settings(commonSettings: _*)
.settings(
    name := "my-project",
    version := myVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= myDependencies
)
.settings(
    scalaxbDispatchVersion in (Compile, scalaxb) := dispatchCoreVersion,
    scalaxbPackageName in (Compile, scalaxb)     := scalaXbGeneratedCodePackageName
    // TODO - store generated source code in src, not target
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scalaxb uses the `sourceManaged` setting ([source](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/blob/master/sbt-scalaxb/src/main/scala/sbtscalaxb/ScalaxbPlugin.scala#L23-L25)). You can change this in you build.sbt, for example:

```
sourceManaged in (Compile, scalaxb) := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "sbt-scalaxb"
```

Comment: This worked for me once I replaced `sourceManaged in scalaxb` with `sourceManaged in (Compile, scalaxb)`. Could you update your answer and then I'll mark it as correct. Thank you so much for the help. +1

Comment: sure, fixed it :)